# PHPUnit How to test a method that uses posix_getgrgid to get group name from gid

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Do you know of a more consistent way to test this class?

This thing takes the gid a linux system uses for group and returns to me the group name.

```
class LinuxIdHandler
{
    /**
     * @param int $gid
     * @return string The linux group name.
     */
    public function getGroupNameByGid($gid)
    {
        $group = posix_getgrgid($gid);
        return $group['name'];
    }
}
```

**BUT...**

Trying to unit test it is giving me trouble because running phpunit on my Macbook tells me that group id 0 is 'wheel'. And my jenkins server running Ubuntu tells me group id 0 is 'root'.

I have what I think is a fairly bad way around it, but I'm interested if anyone has a cleaner way.

```
class LinuxIdHandlerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /** @var LinuxIdHandler */
    private $handler;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->handler = new LinuxIdHandler();
    }

    public function testGetGroupNameByUid()
    {
        switch (PHP_OS) {
            case 'Darwin':
                $groupName = 'wheel';
                break;
            default:
                $groupName = 'root';
        }

        $this->assertEquals($groupName, $this->handler->getGroupNameByGid(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you're doing here is basically attempting to unit test `posix_getgrgid()`. You don't need to do this. Why bother with this test at all? If anything, all you want to test is that `posix_getgrgid()` is called with the expected parameter. Maybe have a read of this ~ http://marcelog.github.io/articles/php_mock_global_functions_for_unit_tests_with_phpunit.html

Comment: True. The only reason I made this class was so I could isolate posix_getgrgid away from another larger class I was testing. These functions being untestable is sort of a pain in the ass. Maybe I just don't need test coverage in this class, thank you for the help and the article.

Comment: I do think mocking `posix_getgrgid()` is the way to go as that's really what you want to test. The return value of that function is irrelevant.

Comment: You're very right. After reading the article I think that's exactly what I will do. Thanks very much for the point in the right direction.

Comment: Feel free to add whatever solution you come up with as an answer to your own question. I'm sure it could be very helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the comments above, why not just test a different gid that returns the proper value? i.e., use gid 1, 100, or even the user gid; whatever returns a value you can consistently check for.

I agree with the comments above, but this approach would also solve your problem.